# import bs4 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a web script, but when I run it it gives me this error:

```
import bs4 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

When I go to my project interpreter, bs4 and beautifulsoup4 are installed. Also, when I run the command `pip install beautifulsoup4`, it says that:

```
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2; python_version >= "3.0" in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (2.1)
```

My Python version is 3.8.0.

Comment: How are you running the python script?  Are you typing `python myscripy.py` at the command line, or do you use an IDE, or how?

Comment: maybe run python3 not python

Comment: @JohnGordon I use IDE PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

**Try to run this command in the same interpreter as your python script.**

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

You may have more than one interpreter setup on your machine, and when you type the command it does not install to the interpreter/virtual environment where your python script is running.

**Solution**

Follow the following steps in order, if applicable to your situation:

1. If you are using an IDE, such as Pycharm or VSCode, you will have an option to **choose your virtual environment**. Keep note of the name of the environment.
2. Then, **activate your virtual environment, and install the package** using the command I specified above. This process can be done from the command line or IDE
3. **Run your python script** in that environment/interpreter

This should have liberally answered the question, but if you want to learn more about virtual environments and interpreters, then use this link.
https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but it still not working, my venv is activated,

Answer (score 0):

I use PyCharm Python3.7 , is ok.

Python3.8 should be fine.

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```